# MongoDB - How to query with a field with calculation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have products like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "Apple",
    "price": 3,
    "stock": 5
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "name": "Banana",
    "price": 1,
    "stock": 6
  }
]
```

How to query and filter the products that have the total price highest? (total price of a product = price * stock)

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

An aggregate query to work with:

1. `$set` - Set `totalPrice` field by multiplying both `price` and `stock` fields.
2. `$sort` - Order by `totalPrice` descending.
3. `$limit` - Take only one document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      totalPrice: {
        "$multiply": [
          "$price",
          "$stock"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      totalPrice: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  }
])
```

Note: Although the above query gets the document with the highest total price, it gets the first and only one document.

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yoUmLtSZMJO)

---

For the above scenario mentioned that possible there are multiple documents with the highest total price, so we need a **ranking**.

1. `$set` - Set `totalPrice` field by multiplying both `price` and `stock` fields.
2. [`$rank`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/rank/) - Rank the documents by sorting with `totalPrice` descending.
3. `$match` - Filter the documents with `rank: 1`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      totalPrice: {
        "$multiply": [
          "$price",
          "$stock"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: {
        totalPrice: -1
      },
      output: {
        rank: {
          $rank: {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      rank: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (`$rank`)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NlhaUP1cfd3)